# WRT310N won't let me change PPPoE password

Tags: router, passwords, pppoe

Something really, really weird is going on with my Linksys WRT310N router. Namely, after:

- multiple resets using the recessed "Reset" button (hold it for 20 seconds when the router is on, did it once when the router was off as well)
- a "Factory defaults" invocation on the router conguration page
- switching to a different machine where I havd never entered the old password, so as to eliminate the browser cache issue

…there still is no way to enter the new password in the "Password" field of the PPPoE settings tab on the "Setup" page. The old password is being recovered from out of nowhere. I check the password field value using the "Inspect element" feature of the browser.

Is this even possible or am I doing / have I made some really silly and obvious mistake?

Comment: Is your browser doing auto-fill? Can you try a different browser or from a different (clean) user account on your computer?

Comment: Auto fill off everywhere; and the first time I enterd the PW on this second machine, there had been no prior attempts on it.

Comment: I've performed a hard 30-30-30 reset, and the password still reappears.